# Getting Delphi to print a two page document onto one A4 with two coulmns

Tags: delphi, printing

I need help setting up printing in Delphi XE3 / RAD Studio XE3. I have created a form intended to be used on a dot matrix printer so the normal .print method does not work as it prints the background of the form. All information is being written into the RichEdit box but spans over two pages. I need that information to be printed onto one A4 page with two columns (half of the information on the left and the rest of the information on the right) on one page
The problem I am having with tabs is, since most of the information will be entered by the user, I will not know how many tabs to use to get the center of the page and thus have alignment problems.

Comment: Did you try to use FastReport?

Comment: It's a popular component for fast creating of different reports. As I understand you want save your data to *.rft or *.doc. So, you can use FastReport. In Internet is many examples for fast start with FastReport.

Comment: Maybe it will be reasonable show part of your code which show how you save your data and show format of your data. Now it's very abstract question.

Comment: Printed pages don't have *tabs* (except the ones contained in the text itself, AKA chr(9) or #9 in Delphi), so I have no idea what you're asking here. What in the world does *cannot get those two documents to be fitted into two tabs on one image* mean? Images don't have tabs either. RichEdit controls store text with formatting characters; they don't have *tabs* either (except the above mentioned tab stops (Chr(9) or #9)). Can you edit your question and explain more clearly what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Also, if your page was designed to print on a dot-matrix printer, chances are it used a fixed-width font and not proportional, so #9 tabs should align just fine. Set the RichEdit to a fixed-width font (Console or Consolas) and use tab characters to align the columns as needed.

Comment: What is type of `redtprint`? And how do you create it?

Comment: Don't add important details in comments, where they get buried in the clutter. Instead, [edit] your question and add them there (which I asked you to do previously).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to send `EM_LINEINDEX` messages to display text in two columns.

Here's an example of added tab-separated columns to a `TRichEdit`. It's clearly not using the text you're trying to output, because I wouldn't likely have the registry entries you're trying to access and therefore couldn't test before posting. It should get you started (but see my note below before doing so).

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to 50 do
    RichEdit1.Lines.Add(Format('%d'#9'This is line %d', [i, i]));
end;
```

The simplest way to print the *TRichEdit* (if all of the content will fit on a single page) is to simply call `TRichEdit.Print`.

With that being said, creating a visual control that you'll never display is usually the wrong approach. All versions of Delphi that have ever been released come with some sort of reporting engine (Quick Reports, Rave Reports, Fast Reports) that are designed to easily create printed output. XE3 comes with Fast Reports, which would make very short work of this type of report and would allow you to control output very accurately. If you're going to be working with Delphi, it's worth becoming familiar with its reporting components; they'll save you lots of work, code and frustration in a very short time frame.